# Hibernate Proxy object serialization issue with spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was working on hibernate and came across an issue while serializing hibernate proxy object within an entity object.

In some of the SO posts it is mentioned that using Hibernate.initialize(ProxyObject) will work ,
But if I have list of items then I have to iterate through all the objects and explicitly call the initialize() method on those objects.

Is there any other way to overcome from this problem ?

My Entities are as follows 
[image]

entity class looks as follows

```
public class GroupMember extends Form {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4728285634057416148L;

    private int grpmid;         
    private User    user;       
    private Boolean grpownr;    
    private Group   grp;        

    //Other Getter and setters

      @OneToOne(targetEntity = Group.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Group_GroupId", referencedColumnName = "GroupId")
    public Group getGrp() {
        return grp;
    }
    public void setGrp(Group grp) {
        this.grp = grp;
    }

}
```

The exception I am getting while returning from my service method - I am checking in rest console.

```
    <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.service.responsepojo.GroupMemberResponse[&quot;grpmbr&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.GroupMember[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.User[&quot;dept&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9[&quot;un&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.service.responsepojo.GroupMemberResponse[&quot;grpmbr&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.GroupMember[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.User[&quot;dept&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9[&quot;un&quot;])</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.service.responsepojo.GroupMemberResponse[&quot;grpmbr&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.GroupMember[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.User[&quot;dept&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9[&quot;un&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.service.responsepojo.GroupMemberResponse[&quot;grpmbr&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.GroupMember[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.User[&quot;dept&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9[&quot;un&quot;])</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.service.responsepojo.GroupMemberResponse[&quot;grpmbr&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.GroupMember[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.User[&quot;dept&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9[&quot;un&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.service.responsepojo.GroupMemberResponse[&quot;grpmbr&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.GroupMember[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.User[&quot;dept&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9[&quot;un&quot;])
    2.      org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:196)
    3.      org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    4.      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    5.      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    6.      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
    7.      org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
    8.      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    9.      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    10.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    11.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    12.     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    13.     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    14.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    15.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    16.     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    17.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    18.     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    19. </pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.service.responsepojo.GroupMemberResponse[&quot;grpmbr&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.GroupMember[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.User[&quot;dept&quot;]-&gt;com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9[&quot;un&quot;])
    20.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    21.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
    22.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:183)
    23.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:559)
    24.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    25.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    26.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    27.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    28.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    29.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    30.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    31.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    32.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    33.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    34.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:120)
    35.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1728)
    36.     org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:193)
    37.     org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    38.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    39.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    40.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
    41.     org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
    42.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    43.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    44.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    45.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    46.     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    47.     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    48.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    49.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    50.     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    51.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    52.     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    53. </pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    54.     org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
    55.     org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
    56.     org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    57.     com.service.pojo.Department_$$_javassist_9.getUn(Department_$$_javassist_9.java)
    58.     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    59.     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    60.     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    61.     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    62.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:653)
    63.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:509)
    64.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    65.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    66.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    67.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    68.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    69.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    70.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    71.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    72.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    73.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    74.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    75.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:120)
    76.     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1728)
    77.     org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:193)
    78.     org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    79.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    80.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    81.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
    82.     org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
    83.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    84.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    85.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    86.     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    87.     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    88.     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    89.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    90.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    91.     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    92.     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    93.     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    94. </pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.34</h3></body></html>
```

Update - 
currently I am using a logic to make object unproxy and returning it to client, but this is costly because I have to iterate through huge list of items

```
Criterion classCriterion = Restrictions.eq(“U.un",
        requestForm.getUn());

Criteria criteria = sessionObject
        .createCriteria(GroupMember.class, "GPM")
        .createAlias("GPM.user”, “U”)
        .add(classCriterion);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<GroupMember> members = (List<GroupMember>)criteria.list();
for (GroupMember groupMember : members) {
    if (groupMember.getGrp() instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        groupMember.setGrp((Group) UnProxy
                .initializeAndUnproxy(groupMember.getGrp()));
    }

    if (groupMember.getGrp().getDept() instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        groupMember.getGrp().setDept((Department) UnProxy
                .initializeAndUnproxy(groupMember.getGrp().getDept()));
    }

    if (groupMember.getUser().getDept() instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        groupMember.getUser().setDept((Department) UnProxy
                .initializeAndUnproxy(groupMember.getUser().getDept()));
    }
}
```

Comment: If I would face the same problem i would consider to map the associated entities with fetch type Eager. (however you should make the call as i don't know your another use cases whether the Lazy make sense or not) But if you would use Eager no proxy objects would be returned. Another way I don't know exactly how to do with criteria now from the top of my head, but if you would use hql to retrieve the data and you will use JOIN FETCH this will return you also the populated collections.